# Error code 206 in Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have an application developed using Java running in Google AppEngine.

Recently came across with following error in google appengine and returned 500 (production environment).

**Error Message:** A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. *(Error code 206)*

The request ran for only 968ms and throwed 500 with the above message.

**Note:** All the other requests that came prior to the same instance of the server didn't cause any errors. They ran successfully.

Please provide the reasons for this kind of failure and what is the remedy for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Ananthakrishnan.

Comment: Computers can fail randomly due to hardware issues for example. If this happended once in 5 years I would attribute this event to sth like that.

Comment: Hi,

This might have happened earlier also...Not sure. But this time it came for the request where the data was supposed to be created. At the end only partial data was created and terminated in 948ms...Other dependent entities (table entries) was not created leaving inconsistent data.

Comment: I would suggest filing an issue in our [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) and linking to it here so we can take a look at this more closely. Including stack traces, error logs and code samples in said issue would also be very helpful.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, they want you to leave appengine so these kind of bugs will appear every now and then and you will get busy (as myself) trying to fix them until you abandon appengine and switch to another framework they prefer. ;-)